# Schema:Recipe vs FOAF

Tags: schema, rich-snippets

I'm using a Drupal site which seems to add FOAF by default, therefore an image would have the following tag:

```
<img typeof="foaf:Image" src="....
```

I'm trying to setup Rich Snippets and on a wrapper I have this div:

```
<div typeof="schema:Recipe">
```

and then I have schema markup on all fields within this.

Using Google Search Console it pulls in all the other values but I've had trouble with the Recipe Image specifically. I'm wondering if there's a conflict going on? How do FOAF and Schema act with each other? What is FOAF even used for?

Google Structured Data tool is only pulling the Image type in, whereas I'd assume it should by default pull the src URL in too?

For reference the Recipe I'm testing is here: http://www.simplybeefandlamb.co.uk/recipes/pulled-beef-brisket

Comment: Could you include a minimal markup example that shows the problem within Google’s tool? If the markup from your example pages changes (or if the page goes 404), this question and answers wouldn’t be very useful for others in the future.